# Is there an efficient way to determine what percentage of an image falls within a specified colour range? (In OpenCV for Android)

Tags: android, opencv

I've written an application which captures a video frame to RGBA format, converts it to HSV (for ease of thresholding) and then thresholds the image. (Essentially, where the camera "sees" the specified colour, it will turn those elements white, where it does not, it will turn those elements black.)

What I would like to do is determine what percentage of the image falls within the specified colour range. My initial idea is to scan through each individual element of the thresholded Mat, and count up the number of white elements to see where the colour is detected. I have two questions - firstly, is this an efficient solution to this problem? Or am I missing something obvious? Secondly, how would I go about accessing the elements of the Mat (if this is the most efficient solution)? I've looked at several questions along with the Mat documentation, however it's a little over my head.

This is the pseudocode I have right now for determining the number of white elements in an image.

```
// Loop through height
   // Loop through width 
       // If Mat element (height, width) is white, add 1 to the total 

// Compare total to the total number of elements in the image (height * width)
```

**Edit:** I've found how to access individual elements of a Mat (I was over-thinking it and confusing myself looking at some irrelevant information in a tutorial I'd found. I'm including how to do it below, however I would welcome any ideas about a more efficient way to do this, or the knowledge that I'm already doing this as efficiently as possible, if I am! Thanks!

```
for(int h=0; h<mHSVThreshed.height(); h++){
    for(int w=0; w<mHSVThreshed.width(); w++) {
        double element = mHSVThreshed.get(h, w)[0]; 
        }
}
```

To access a Mat with multiple channels, you would use `mHSV.get(h, w)[1] mHSV.get(h, w)[2]` etc.

Comment: Why don't you do this while you convert it into HSV. That way you don't have to pass over the data twice.

Comment: (Sorry I should have included the full code so far (or at least pseudocode) - I do a simple conversion of the whole Mat from RGBA to HSV, then threshold the HSV, then run this over the threshed HSV since it will just be white/black)

Comment: I may be a bit confused - you can do all of this in one pass of the RGBA image. Go over each pixel -> convert to HSV -> change pixel to white (if it falls into range) -> add to detected colour pixel count. At the end of the operation you can just check what percentage of white pixels you have over your total pixel count.

Comment: How would you do this? Would this be if you converted the pixels manually? The Mat can be converted between colour spaces in one line of code, "Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);"

Comment: One line of code doesn't mean it's more or less efficient (it could be doing the same thing). Try doing all three steps in one pass over and benchmark it to see any difference in performance.

Comment: @ShimmerGeek http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor tells you how to convert from RGB to HSV manually. If you only care about H channel, you only need to compute H from R, G, and B, which is more efficient than using `cvtColor`.

Comment: Thanks @cxyzs7 - I actually intended to look at the value of mHSVThreshed, rather than mHSV - I mistakenly pasted the wrong code. I'll fix that :) Thank you for such a helpful link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this for speed.

```
unsigned int accumulator=0;
for(int i=0;i<yourMat.rows;i++){
    unsigned char *row=yourMat.ptr(i);
    for(int j=0;j<yourMat.cols;j++)
        accumulator+=row[j];
}
accumulator/=(yourMat.cols*yourMat.rows);
```

This assumes that you have thresholded to a value of 1 rather than 255 or something else. It should be much faster than the `Mat::get()` function because it only worries about the width step once per row.